# search a document

Tags: c#, .net, string-matching

I am currently working on a project where I need to search for phrases and words in a word document through code.

Basically a Word document will be uploaded and then searched for some words.
What would be the most efficient way to do this?

**Edit:** I'm more interested in the what to use to read the document (i.e. is MS Interop the best way?) and then if it would be very advantageous to index it before searching (if so how?).

**Edit:** The search could potentially be for thousands of phrases.

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Answer (score 0):

[Open a word document in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555)

After that it's just a matter of using the `Contains` method, or something like that. It's really not that difficult. You might want to watch cases with lower- and uppercase letters.

And just do something like this: (Pseudo Code)

```
string[] stuffToFind = new string[] {"Google", "is your best friend"};

for (int i = 0; i < stuffToFind.Length; i++;)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < document.Length; j++)
    {
        if(document[j].Contains(stuffToFind[i]))
            Console.Writeline("Yeay, we found something");
    }
}
```

I don't really like this solution though. It also kind of depends on what the word document object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a good way to find patterns. You can find information about the same here:

[REGEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would use a free library from MS called [`OpenXML SDK 2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) to open the word document (works with Word 2007 and up)... this library works without the need to have word installed... and then you can extract the text and search it anyway you like - for example with [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) ...

When you extract the text you can index it by storing all words/phrases with context information (posision etc.) in a DB so you would only need to `SELECT` from the DB when a user gives you phrase to search - the design of the index is up to you - will you need case-insensitive search ? etc.

Another option would be to use [Solr/Lucene](http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx) for indexing and access that index via API provide the UI for the search...